how to monitor traffic in monit by traffic I mean bandwidth and is that possible using monit
I have a question regarding monit is it possible to monitor traffic in monit I kind don't know if that is possible to be traffic. by traffic I mean my bandwidth I have two in my vps incoming and outgoing I tried to search but I think this related to different tool not monit... any help !!!
I am thinking of something like sh or cron code or something that is what I can think of

I have no idea what you mean by traffic vs bandwidth. Could you please clarify what you mean by these terms?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@DanielK yes my dear when i subscribe to host they told me that I have outgoing traffic = 32TB that is what I am trying to monitor

Monit collect information from the used interface.
check network Ethernet with interface en0
  if failed link for 5 times within 15 cycles then unmonitor
     else if recovered then alert
  if saturation > 5% then alert
  if upload > 500 kB then alert
  if download > 500 kB then alert

Some more information abould network interface tests are available in the manual, see https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#NETWORK-INTERFACE-TESTS
Unfortunately the capability depends to the palttform and interface type. A simple incomming/outgoing traffice counter is not available (I can not find a counter based on the interface to collect this data with Monit).
A suggestion only,
Lutz
